# Parsing problem while testing API Services with Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I'm trying to test my API with Moq but I'm having trouble with the mocked service and the execution of the test.

**Unit test** code:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly INearEarthObjectService _repo;
    Mock<INearEarthObjectService> _mockRepo = new Mock<INearEarthObjectService>();
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddTransient<INearEarthObjectService, NearEarthObjectService>();
        services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/") });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        _repo = serviceProvider.GetService<INearEarthObjectService>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void Test1()
    {
        _mockRepo.Setup(p => p.GetAllNeos(2)).Returns(Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<NearEarthObjectDTO>>).Verifiable();

        var result = _mockRepo.Object.GetAllNeos(2);

        Assert.True(result.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble in this **line**:

```
var result = _mockRepo.Object.GetAllNeos(2);
```

I gives me this **exception**:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NasaApi.Models.NearEarthObjectDTO]'.'
```

My **Service** code if it is useful:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<NearEarthObjectDTO>> GetAllNeos(int days)
    {
        //Variable declaration
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime nextday = today.AddDays(days);
        List<NearEarthObjectDTO> list = new List<NearEarthObjectDTO>();
        NearEarthObjectDTO neo;

        //URL parsing & data request
        var complete_url = url + start_date_param + today.Date.ToString(
            "yyyy-MM-dd") + "&" + end_date_param + nextday.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "&" + detailed_param + "&" + api_key_param;
        var feed = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>(complete_url);

        //Data filtering and parsing into DTO
        if (feed != null)
        {
            foreach (var register in feed.near_earth_objects)
            {
                foreach(var item in register.Value)
                {
                    neo = new NearEarthObjectDTO();
                    neo.Id = item.id;
                    neo.Nombre = item.name;
                    neo.Fecha = item.close_approach_data[0].close_approach_date;
                    neo.Velocidad = item.close_approach_data[0].relative_velocity.kilometers_per_hour;
                    neo.Diametro = DiameterCalc.Calc(item.estimated_diameter.meters.estimated_diameter_min,
                        item.estimated_diameter.meters.estimated_diameter_min);
                    neo.Planeta = item.close_approach_data[0].orbiting_body;

                    if (item.is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid && neo.Planeta.Equals("Earth") && !list.Contains(neo))
                    {
                        list.Add(neo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Return just the top 3 biggest potentially hazardous asteroids
        return list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Diametro).Take(3);
    }
```

I don't know where is the parsing problem because I'm a using a **var** which is supposed to adapt to any type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't test the mock object. Your mock setup should be something like

```
_mockRepo.Setup(p => p.GetAllNeos(It.IsAny<int>)).ReturnsAsync(new List<NearEarthObjectDTO>()).Verifiable();
```

Here you are saying when GetAllNeos() gets called with any `int` it should return my `List` (which would be some fake data that the GetAllNeos() function is to return)